# Android dialog title height

Tags: android, dialog

In my android app there is a contest module, in which a question and its options will display.it working fine but when we adding long question it wont displaying full text.
i am using dialog box for this, and my dialogbox.xml look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#53412d" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/namelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5am-9am" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9am-1pm" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1pm-5pm" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5pm-9pm" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namelayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms1"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms2"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms3"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms4"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Send" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my activity.java i write like

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HelloFMActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);
dialog.setTitle("my long question bla bla bla bla bla bla bla");
```

Comment: You already use layout dialogbox .Please customize layout there.So don't need setTitle  .

Comment: What exacly do you want to happen..?

Answer (score 1):

Add another TextView in the layout for the question. Avoid setting the question as title of the dialog.

Comment: I am new to android...How to add new textview and how to connect to java file

Comment: @JasirAlwafaa Please add TextView in your layout first as a title

Answer (score 1):

You can see this link

> http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111

As your code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                    //setting custom layout to dialog
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cusotm_dialog_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another tricks

Create **TextView By Programmatic** way

```
    TextView TvTitle =  new TextView(YourclassName.this);
    TvTitle.setText("Alert");
    TvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    TvTitle.setTextSize(30);
    TvTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    Dialog_Object.setCustomTitle(TvTitle);
```

Or

**Customize your Dialog layout** 
Like

```
    Dialog custom_connection_dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);
    custom_connection_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((0xff000000)));
    custom_connection_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    custom_connection_dialog.setCancelable(true);
    custom_connection_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    custom_connection_dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    Button  TurnAgain = (Button) custom_connection_dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonID);
    TurnAgain.setOnClickListener(this);
    custom_connection_dialog.show();
```

Edit

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    params.setMargins(,,,);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Try this way .Let me inform

Comment: i created a textview and add  **TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
     text.setText("What time do you get to hear Mike and Shiela on Bueno Mano");
     text.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 80);**  i want to add a margin bottom..how to add

Comment: it saying setMargins is undefined for the type textview

Comment: @JasirAlwafaa Whats your min sdk version ?

Comment: my min sdk version is 13

Comment: now it showing error like  **Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams) is 
  undefined
 - LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a variable
 - LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a type
 - LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a variable**

Comment: @JasirAlwafaa Did you import properly

Comment: yes i import import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams; is it ryt?

Comment: android.widget.LinearLayoutLayout.LayoutParams;

Comment: Can u pls check the screenshot what i am getting.question and options are overlaping.i want to add a margin below question.https://drive.google.com/a/alwafaagroup.com/file/d/0B4V9jFR967zjckVFcnQyaUJzQWM/view

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFMActivity.this);
alertDialog.setTitle("your title");
alertDialog.setMessage("my long question bla bla bla bla bla bla bla");
```

instead of

```
dialog.setTitle("my long question bla bla bla bla bla bla bla");
```

Comment: But it showing like The method setMessage(String) is undefined for the type Dialog...................i ma new to android...